# How to access an element in UserControl from the MainPage?

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps

I have a `UserControl` that is an ItemTemplate for a FlipView that exists in my MainPage. This `UserControl` contains a Canvas which name is `x:Name="InkCanvas"`.

And I want to initialise this Canvas and access it from my `MainPage.xaml.cs`:

```
private readonly CanvasManager m_CanvasManager;
m_CanvasManager = new CanvasManager(InkCanvas);
```

Setting it to `static` couldn't help! How can it be possible?

Comment: If you have the user control in MainPage, you can access it using `UserControlName.InkCanvas` or create a public method in the user control to return the canvas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that if this `UserControl` is not my current `ItemTemplate`: I can't access any of its controls.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
private readonly CanvasManager m_CanvasManager;
this.InkCanvas = new CanvasManager();
m_CanvasManager = this.InkCanvas;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add to your `UserControl.cs` this method:

```
public Canvas GetInkCanvas()
{
   return InkCanvas;
}
```

And use it form `MainPage.cs`:

```
var canvas = userControl.GetInkCanvas(); // userControl - here is the instanse of UserControl.
```

But in general - this is not a good idea to share your `Canvas` from your `UserControl`.

Comment: What's a good idea? The UserControl should be inside my MainPage?

Comment: You can move all logic for Canvas manipulation incide UserControl.cs (as public method). Then add UserControl to the necessary place to MainPage.xaml. In MainPage.cs - you will have instance of UserControl (from xaml) and can call all public methods from UserControl.cs.

Answer (score 0):

What I understand is:
Your user control is an item template for a FlipView, and you can't find way to access its content, so, what you need is:

```
(yourFlipView.Items[index] as YourUserControl).getCanvas();
```

The `getCanvas()` is the getter of the canvas you want to access in your user control, you have to implement it in YourUserControl.cs